# Count number of elements within a element using SAX

Tags: android, xml, sax

is there any way to count the number of elements within another element using SAX Parser?
For example I'm using this xml file:

`<varfield id = "xxx">`
`<subfield label = "xxx">yyy</subfield>`
`<subfield label = "xxx">yyy</subfield>`
`<subfield label = "xxx">yyy</subfield>`
`</varfield>`

How do i get the number of "subfield" tags within the "varfield tag"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily with dom parser

Comment: Thanks, but if possible I wanna use SAX. Its much faster.

Comment: @Joel: How often do you have to do these calculations? Is speed actually an issue?

Comment: @Robert: Hey sry for the late reply. Actually I was having trouble setting the text in textview based on the subfield tags. I was able to retrieve all the data within those tags but when i set into the textviews, it turns out null or empty as the app keeps running through the if-else code and resetting my textviews with "". So I thought of counting the subfield tags and then run the app through a for-loop and the stop resetting my textviews with "".